# Filling in missing inbetween values with known two values in excel or python

Tags: python, excel, graph, missing-data, fill

I used known x and y values to do scatter plots but how can I find a y value based on x values. For instance, the data below is a small part of the scatter plot but how do I find the all depth values  between 232 and 307 distance?

[image]

[image]

can it be done on excel or python?

Comment: `how do I find the all depth values between 232 and 307 distance?` - you interpolate.

Comment: Probably a duplicate but I'm voting to close as too broad.